# Title: gphoto2 not detecting SD card folders and files on Sony Alpha A7R IV

Tags: raspberry-pi3, libgphoto2

I'm currently facing an issue with gphoto2 when trying to access the SD card of my Sony Alpha A7R IV camera. Despite being able to capture images using gphoto2, when I run the command gphoto2 --list-files, I receive the message: "There is no files in folder."

Here are some details about my setup:

Camera: Sony Alpha A7R IV
OS: Debian on a Raspberry Pi 3
gphoto2 version: gphoto 2.5.27
SD card structure: has two folders, first one called private. Second one called DCIM, this is where the pictures are saved.

Capturing images works successfully using gphoto2.
The SD card has two folders in the root directory, but they are not detected by gphoto2.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem with this camera model, and do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Are there any specific configurations needed for the Sony Alpha A7R IV with gphoto2?

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

Verifying that the camera is set to store images on the SD card.
Exploring the camera storage using various gphoto2 commands.
Despite these efforts, gphoto2 is not recognizing the SD card folders and files. I suspect there might be a configuration issue or a specific setting for the Sony Alpha A7R IV.